# Emacs mode question

Tags: objective-c, emacs

I'm starting to use objective C, and objective C mode works perfectly fine. However, ObjC uses .h files, just like C and C++. I need to be able to use all three. Does anyone know how to get emacs to tell if it should be in objC mode or C/C++ mode?

EDIT: There seems to be some confusion on what I'm asking for. The problem is that I have some .h files that are associated with .m files, and some .h files that are associated with .c files and some that are associated with .cpp files. What I *WANT* is something that I can stick in my c-mode-common-hook or somewhere that will check to see if it's an objective C .h file, and then force it to objective C-mode, or something. The idea being that then I can just open a .h file and it will automatically be in the correct mode.

Obviously I can manually change mode when I'm in the file, but that's a pain, and I often forget until I hit tab and something wacky happens. This is the solution I'm using now.

I think that the header comment is probably the right way to do this, but in order for it to be TRULY useful, I need to figure out how to get XCode to put the comment in there when It's creating the file for me...

EDIT2:

I'm currently using the header-comment solution. Until I can figure out how to make XCode automatically add the comment, I'm using the following elisp function:

```
(defun bp-add-objC-comment ()
  "Adds the /* -*- mode: objc -*- */ line at the top of the file"
  (interactive)
  (objc-mode)
  (let((p (point)))
    (goto-char 0)
    (insert "/* -*- mode: objc -*- */\n")
    (goto-char (+ p  (length "/* -*- mode: objc -*- */\n")))))
```

Comment: I don't understand your objection? objective C .h files are different than C++ .h files. I want to use the correct mode.

Comment: You can use a marker instead of calculating the return position yourself: (let ((m (point-marker))) (goto-char 0) (insert "...") (goto-char (marker-position m)))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can put a comment like this in the first line of the file:

```
/* -*- mode: objc -*- */
```

or

```
// -*- mode: c++ -*-
```

as appropriate.  More details in [Specifying File Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) in the Emacs manual.

Comment: that will work, yes. I was looking for a LITTLE less effort, but I can make a script to do that...

Comment: @legoscia It's not working in my case, can you suggest how it will work?

Comment: @Dinesh_Kachhot Try to come up with the smallest possible file that reproduces the problem, and post it as a question over at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, how about a solution that doesn't require putting a special comment in the file?

Check this out:

```
;; need find-file to do this
(require 'find-file)
;; find-file doesn't grok objc files for some reason, add that
(push ".m" (cadr (assoc "\\.h\\'" cc-other-file-alist)))

(defun my-find-proper-mode ()
  (interactive)
  ;; only run on .h files
  (when (string-match "\\.h\\'" (buffer-file-name))
    (save-window-excursion
      (save-excursion
        (let* ((alist (append auto-mode-alist nil))  ;; use whatever auto-mode-alist has
               (ff-ignore-include t)                 ;; operate on buffer name only
               (src (ff-other-file-name))            ;; find the src file corresponding to .h
               re mode)
          ;; go through the association list
          ;; and find the mode associated with the source file
          ;; that is the mode we want to use for the .h file
          (while (and alist
                      (setq mode (cdar alist))
                      (setq re (caar alist))
                      (not (string-match re src)))
            (setq alist (cdr alist)))
          (when mode (funcall mode)))))))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-find-proper-mode)
```

This uses Emacs' built in package to find the corresponding .h/.cc files.  So, if the header file you just opened corresponds to a file in c++-mode, the .h file gets put in that mode, if the source is a objc-mode file, the header gets put in that mode.

No special Emacs variables in the comments required.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look at that more carefully to see exactly how it is working. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I would use [eproject](http://github.com/jrockway/eproject/) to help me handle this.  Assuming that I don't mix-and-match languages inside a given project, I could just create a `.eproject` file in the project root that contains the text:

```
:cc-header-type :objc
```

Then, I'd set some sort of default mode for .h files:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("[.]h$" . c-mode))
```

Then, add a hook for that mode:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda ()
    (let ((header-style (eproject-attribute :cc-header-type)))
        (when (and header-style
                   (string-match "[.]h$" (buffer-file-name)))
            (case header-style
                (:objc (objc-mode))
                (:c++  (c++-mode))
                (:c    (c-mode))))))
```

Now the mode will be changed automatically according to the setting you make in the `.eproject` file.  (Note that the `.eproject` file is not the only way to set variables for eproject; if you have a heuristic to detect objective c projects, eproject can get the variable that way also.)

Anyway, if this works for you, let me know so I can add it to the [eproject wiki](http://wiki.github.com/jrockway/eproject/).

Comment: ObjC projects frequently contain C++.  There's even ObjC++ dialects.